# How to use Sed command to get following output?

Tags: sed

My input is:

```
"INTC_KEY,ABC1|OBJID,ABC2"
```

And I want to send the output to a file like:

```
DDS.INTC_KEY = REPL.OBJID AND DDS.ABC1 = REPL.ABC2
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
sed 's/^/DDS./g' | sed 's/|/=REPL./g' | tr '\n' '~' | sed 's/~/_N~/g' | sed 's/~$/\n/g' | sed 's/~/~\n/g' | sed 's/~/ AND/g' > ${LOG_DIR}/JOIN.tmp
```

Comment: You should show some evidence of what you have already tried (or researched).

Comment: Hi Anthony, This is what I did " sed  's/^/DDS./g' |  sed  's/|/=REPL./g' | tr '\n' '~' | sed 's/~/_N~/g' | sed 's/~$/\n/g' | sed 's/~/~\n/g' | sed 's/~/ AND/g' >  ${LOG_DIR}/JOIN.tmp"

Comment: I've edited your question to include that information – but it’s best if you edit the question yourself. In general, you’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if your question is clearer, shows some of the research you’ve done, what you’ve tried, what errors you got, etc. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank You Anthony.

Comment: In order for people to answer this question properly, you’d also need to show a range of example input so people know what kind of text the regular expressions should match – and what kind of text *shouldn’t* be matched. The more context you supply, the better, e.g., will all the key-value pairs be separated using commas and vertical bars (`|`)?, does every line contain precisely 2 key-value pairs?, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the single line of input, the following regular expression will transform the input into the desired output:

```
s/"\([^,]*\),\([^|]*\)|\([^,]*\),\(.*\)"/DDS.\1 = REPL.\3 AND DDS.\2 = REPL.\4/
```

This shell command shows it working:

```
$ echo '"INTC_KEY,ABC1|OBJID,ABC2"' | sed 's/"\([^,]*\),\([^|]*\)|\([^,]*\),\(.*\)"/DDS.\1 = REPL.\3 AND DDS.\2 = REPL.\4/'

DDS.INTC_KEY = REPL.OBJID AND DDS.ABC1 = REPL.ABC2
```

The regular expression basically matches four pieces of text (using the escaped parentheses), delimited by the commas and vertical bar and made available as the `\1`-`\4` back references for the substitution.

Note: I’ve tried to stick to using the features of [standard `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and I tested using GNU sed with the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable set to 1 to emulate standard sed.

Comment: Thank you so much Anthony. This is working fine now. I am new to this platform. I will take care of things you mentioned. Will be more clear.

Comment: You're welcome @EshanChintawar  Since this answer worked for you, you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark to the left.
This marks the question as *answered* and (with upvotes) is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.
Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!